# Does Euler-lagrange Equation hold with discontinuous integrand?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Suppose I have a function $Heaviside(x-1) \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$ or some other discontinuous function, how do I find the minima with E-L Eqn or in other way?

Comment: Discontinuous functions aren't differentiable, so my first thought would be "no". But it depends on the limits of integration, for example, if the interval happens to be small enough such that the integrand is differentiable there (at least), you could work your way around it. Take my comment with a grain of salt, though

Comment: The physicist's way of doing this is approximate all discontinuous function by smooth functions, solve the equation and then taking limit by sending the smooth function to the discontinuous function. Finally, only keep those portion of result which is independent of how you approximate the discontinuous function and taking limit. For practical application, this is the right approach because the discontinuous function (and in fact, every function you write down in your problem) itself is an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

For this example, the discontinuity is just a boundary between two regions where Euler-Lagrange, or other methods, can be applied. So examine the regions separately, examine the function at the boundary (limits from either side), and compare the points. The minima will lie among all of them.

It is only when the function is not differentiable at more than isolated points that differential methods fail completely.